# Google Cloud Function works with "503 Service Unavailable" message

Tags: google-cloud-platform, async-await, google-cloud-functions

I have a GC Function that triggers cron-job. Almost everything works well, except I get error in Logs "Service unavailable" even though it works (runs API call).
This my code:

```
exports.helloPubSub = (event, context) => {
  const message = event.data
    ? Buffer.from(event.data, 'base64').toString()
    : 'Function';
  console.log("message:", message);

  const url = `example.com`
  const targetAudience = '12345';

  const {GoogleAuth} = require('google-auth-library');
  const auth = new GoogleAuth();

  async function request() {
    const client = await auth.getIdTokenClient(targetAudience);
    const res = await client.request({
      'url': url,
      'method': 'post', 
      'data': {
        'token': 'myToken'
      }});
    console.info(res.data);
  }

  request().catch(err => {
    console.error(err.message);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });

};
```

The error "Service unavailable" appears after 5 minutes as the function starts. The function is performed for 7 minutes every 10 minutes, so there is time gap between next starting.

The question is, is it something with the function or with time-limit in GC? Any thoughts?

**Updated:**

This is my logs:
[image]

Comment: What do you have in the logs? A 503 is a crash of your function, you should have logs to understand what is going on!

Comment: I'he added logs. As I mentioned it does not crash my function, I just get this error ... and I want to fix it.

Comment: Can you describe how do you deploy your function and what's the API call that you perform (in which delay it answers)?

Comment: It's a simple scheduler (runs every 10 min) that runs GC function via pub/sub. The function call API (post method) which in turn trigger cron-job (it's kind of integration that takes 7-8 min) in cakephp 2.

Comment: Ok, but what are the parameters of your Cloud Functions? And do you have logs on the cakephp2 service side? Does the 503 come from there?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not completely understad what parameters are you asking about? I do not see any such logs in cakephp.

Comment: How do you deploy your functions? Did you put a timeout? A retry policy? And is all went fine on cakephp side?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation:

[HTTP status and error codes for JSON](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/status-codes)

`503—Service Unavailable` is a backendError (internal error), and you are encouraged to try again using [truncated exponentioal backoff](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I do not like GCP documentation, maybe you have some examples how to use it?

Comment: Google Cloud Client Libraries for Node.js can automatically use backoff strategies to retry requests with the autoRetry parameter. [link](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff#example_implementations)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not help ... I still get error

Comment: The error seems to come from the Apache server that you are calling with the url in your Cloud Function. If this is a transient issue you should enable some try-catch structure in your code to retry the request, otherwise you might want to inspect the logs of your backend to know why is it failing.